# Sum of the first $n$ palindromes

Tags: programming, palindrome

We put together a problem to be solved programmatically, and we know at lower numbers there is a solution to this problem. How would we go about proving whether the below problem has an answer, as our standard computational approaches do not yield a value.

> $X$ is the sum of the first $N$ palindromes. Find the value for $N$ in which $X$ is both over $3$ million and is in it's self palindromic.

We used JS to create a function which finds lower values, but the integers are too large to find a solution where x is greater than 3m

```
function isPalindrome(x) {
    const s = `${x}`;

    for (let i = 0; i < (s.length - 1) / 2; i++) {
        if (s[i] !== s[s.length - i - 1]) return false
    }
    return true
}

function quickExhaustiveSearch(limit) {
    let i = 0,
        n = 0, // number of pals
        x = 0; // sum of N first pal

    console.log(`Solving for x>${limit} starting at i=${i} and n=${n}`);

    while (x < limit || !isPalindrome(x)) {
        if (isPalindrome(i)) {
            x += i;
            n++;
            console.log({x, i, n});
        }
        i++
    }

    console.log('Solution is', x, i, n);
}
```

Comment: What approach did you use?

Comment: Purely programmatic, i'll update the question with the code we used - but it reaches max integer before finding a solution where x is greater than 3m

Comment: I left python code running, and there is no solution for $N\lt 2\times10^9$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, here's another Python script. It does the same job as Vepir's code, except it uses a generator to construct the palindromes directly so it's a *lot* faster. It also puts its progress reports on a single line.

```
def palgen():
    i = 1
    while True:
        ii = 10 * i
        r = range(i, ii)
        for j in r:
            s = str(j)
            yield s + s[-2::-1]
        for j in r:
            s = str(j)
            yield s + s[::-1]
        i = ii

total = 0
for i, s in enumerate(palgen(), 1):
    total += int(s)
    z = str(total)
    if z == z[::-1]:
        print(z, s, i)
    if i % 100000 == 0:
        print(' progress', z, s, i, end='\r', flush=True)
```

**some output**

```
1 1 1
3 2 2
6 3 3
111 33 12
353 77 16
7557 383 47
2376732 21512 314
 progress 2045049045042045044 2000001000002 3000000
```

That run took 35 seconds on this ancient 2GHz 32 bit machine.

Comment: I updated my post as well, in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Vepir Oh well. It's interesting that my code is so close to Quant Metropolis's. But as the Zen of Python says: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". :)

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer:** *(Would be great if someone can prove this observation)*

I wrote a simple python script to sum palindromes: (python has no integer limit)

---

**Update:** Decided to listen to [DanielV](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/97045/danielv)'s comment, and optimized my script (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344628/5821790)):

```
#generates all palindromes in range
list = palindromes(1, 10**12)

count = 0
pastCount = 0
palindrome =  0

#sums them and check each sum for being a palindrome
for x in list:
    count += x
    palindrome += 1

    # print out only the newest palindromic sum
    if (pastCount != count and str(count) == str(count)[::-1]):
        print (count, palindrome)
        pastCount = count

    # This prints sum of the entire range (last sum)
    if (x == list[-1]):
        print ("progress:", count, palindrome)
```

Where the `palindromes()` function is in the linked answer.

$X$, Palindromic sums, it found: $1, 3, 6, 111, 353, 7557, 2376732$

(For first $N$ palindromes: $1, 2, 3, 12, 16, 47, 314$)

This sequence is also in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A046488) and looks like that are all terms there is.

> By the look of it, I would bet on that the next sum of palindromes
>   which is also palindromic, does not exist; that there is no solution
>   for $N$ if $X$ is over three million.

But I'm not sure how to prove this.

Here is the output: (took few seconds)

```
1 1
3 2
6 3
111 12
353 16
7557 47
2376732 314
progress: 545046045045045041 1999999
```

Where you can see that if $N$ existed, it is surely greater than two million ($N\ge2000000$), where its $X$ is surely greater than $5\times10^{17}$, which is way beyond your three million lower bound.

Comment: Good lord.  Rather than checking if a number is a palindrome, you should just construct a palindrome out of an arbitrary number.  Like if $x = 123$ then you have found palindromes $123321$ and $12321$.

Comment: @DanielV Yes, that would be the right and faster approach, but in this particular case, this is sufficient to show that the next term is no where near, if it exists; as the next term was probably searched for but was not found.

Comment: @DanielV I updated my post, in the end.